# Why is my variable not returning anything when console.logging it works?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to add 2 functionalities for a calculator project:

1. When a number button is clicked it will display on the calculator gui
2. to add that value into the variable "num".

In the GetNumber function, when I click a button this line successfully outputs that number onto the calculator for step 1.

```
outputBox.textContent += e.target.classList[1]
```

What I am struggling with is getting a return value of "num". I do the same thing here which works fine and correctly outputs the numbers when I console.log(num) however when I try to return "num" nothing comes back.

```
num += e.target.classList[1]
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kenref/pen/RwYmYbx?editors=0010) here for reference. I am testing it with the equals function so that when the equals button is clicked on the calculator, if working properly, it should output the numbers into the console.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calcContainer">
        <div id="outputBox">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="number 7">7</button>
            <button class="number 8">8</button>
            <button class="number 9">9</button>
            <button class="operator ÷">÷</button>
            <button class="number 4">4</button>
            <button class="number 5">5</button>
            <button class="number 6">6</button>
            <button class="operator x">x</button>
            <button class="number 1">1</button>
            <button class="number 2">2</button>
            <button class="number 3">3</button>
            <button class="operator -">-</button>
            <button class="number 0">0</button>
            <button id="clear">AC</button>
            <button id="equals">=</button>
            <button class="operator +">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
let outputBox = document.getElementById("outputBox");
const number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
const operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
const equalsButton = document.getElementById("equals")

let a = "", middle = "", b = "", runningTotal = 0

function getNumber(num) {
    for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            outputBox.textContent += e.target.classList[1]
            num += e.target.classList[1]
            console.log(num)
        })
    }
    return num
}


a = getNumber(a)

function equals(abc) {
    equalsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(abc)
    })
}

equals(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new code with fix to your issue.

```
let outputBox = document.getElementById("outputBox");
const numberContainer = document.getElementById("numbers");
const operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
const equalsButton = document.getElementById("equals")

let a = "", middle = "", b = "", runningTotal = 0;

function getNumber(num) {
  return (e) => {
    outputBox.textContent += e.target.textContent;
    num += e.target.textContent;
    console.log(num);
  };
}

for (let i = 0; i < numberContainer.children.length; i++) {
  numberContainer.children[i].addEventListener("click", getNumber(a));
}

function equals(abc) {
  equalsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(abc)
  })
}

equals(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this approach?

```
let a = "", middle = "", b = "", output = "", num = ""

    for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            outputBox.textContent += e.target.classList[1]
            num += e.target.classList[1]
            output = num
        })
    }

    equalsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(output)
    })
```